# Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: css, angular

I have an img tag inside a div and I wanted to use ngClass to mirror the image. When I use the ngClass in the img tag I got an error : Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'img'

My component.ts file:

```
imgFlipStyleY = 'img-defaultY';
flipY(){
    if(this.imgFlipStyleY == 'img-changeY') {
      this.imgFlipStyleY = 'img-defaultY';
    } else {
      this.imgFlipStyleY = 'img-changeY';
    }
  }
```

The app.component.html file:

```
    <div class="container">
            <img [src]="previewUrl" [ngClass]="[imgStyle]"  [style.filter]="'grayscale('+grayScale+')'"/>
<button  (click)="flipY()">Flip</button>                 
        </div>
```

My component.css file:

```
.img-defaultY {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}

.img-changeY {
  transform: rotateY(-0.5turn);
}
```

My app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';



@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, MatSliderModule, HttpClientModule, NgbModule  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I imported the CommonModule in my app.module so I don't know what's the problem... Can anyone help me?

Comment: What does `imgStyle` refer to? If you are trying to set a class from a variable, use `[class]="imgStyle"`, where `imgStyle` could be  `"img-defaultY"` or `"img-changeY"`.

Answer (score 2):

How does your module looks like? Maybe you forgot to import `CommonModule` in your module i.e.:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, // <- this here
    // other imports
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```